# Why and when do we use response.end() and return response.end() in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've recently started to learn node.js  and I have come across one of the chapters to get an idea about 'Upload files'. As you can see the code below( I've commented over the line where i have doubt), is it necessary to write "return res.end();" because "res.end();" gives the output. So, here arises the question, like, when, why and where do we use 'return' keyword along with 'res.end()'.

```
var http = require('http');
var formidable = require('formidable');
var fs = require('fs');
var mv = require('mv');

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  if (req.url == '/fileupload') {
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
    form.parse(req, function (err, fields, files) {
      var oldpath = files.filetoupload.path;
      var newpath = 'C:/Users/Your Name/' + files.filetoupload.name;
      mv(oldpath, newpath, function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        res.write('File uploaded and moved!');
        res.end();
      });
 });
  } else {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html'});
    res.write('<form action="fileupload" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data">');
    res.write('<input type="file" name="filetoupload"><br>');
    res.write('<input type="submit">');
    res.write('</form>');
    return res.end();//       <------------HERE
  }
}).listen(8080);
```

Comment: It's a short way to write `res.end(); return;`. There is no return value from `end()` IIRC, and the value you return in the request listener is ignored anyway.

Comment: "*I have come across one of the chapters to get an idea about 'Upload files'.*" - which book are you reading?

Comment: Hi Bergi, well, in fact, it's not the book as such but its the tutorials from w3schools and under the nodejs tutorials comes this topic.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `return` in `return res.end();` is only for code flow control to exit the function and not execute any more code in that function.  The server that calls your request handler callback does not pay any attention to a return value so the code is not trying to return a value.  It's just to stop any further execution in the function.

In the specific context you show where `res.end()` is on the last line of the function, there is NO functional difference at all between `res.end()` and `return res.send()`.

In some other contexts, there might be some other code that could still execute later in the function and `return` is one way to keep that code from executing.  `return res.end()` is sometimes used as a shortcut to avoid an `else` clause as in something like this:

```
 if (err) {
     return res.status(500).end();
 }
 // other code here for non-error case
```

Instead of doing this:

```
 if (err) {
     res.status(500).end();
 } else {
    // other code here for non-error case
 }
```

Both of those are functionally the same.  The `return` in the first is used as a shortcut to avoid the `else` in the second (not personally my favorite coding style, but a legit choice if desired).

---

FYI, in that code you show, the `if (err) throw err;` inside an async callback is almost never the proper way to do error handling because the exception goes into some async infrastructure where you can't catch it or do anything intelligent with it.  I know your question wasn't about this, but since you're learning node.js, I thought I'd point this out.  In this particular case, you should probably send the client a 5xx error status.

Comment: As for the beginner stage, I have no idea where to begin node.js but to seek help from some online tutorials. Is there a better way of learning? Some of the books i referred are too much advanced and it's hard for me to understand. If you have any suggestions please could you share? Thank you.

Comment: @jfriend00 It might help me too, can you recommend some resources? Isn't res.end() asynchronous operation?

Comment: so the command res.end() DOESN'T end the function? the function will continue to execute code after that command?

Comment: @JuanPerez - Yes, that's correct.  `res.send()` is just a function call.  It doesn't tell the JS interpreter to stop executing more code.

Comment: @JuanPerez - I meant `res.end()`, but same either way.  Those are just function calls, not directives to the JS interpreter.